# Point all request back to localhost

Tags: python, sockets, dns

I am working on a small captive portal using python. I would like to redirect the user to a custom a page on a local server i created. My question, how to resolve all sites (e.g: google.com) the user enters to localhost or 127.0.0.1.  i have seen seen site like localtest.me and fuf.me point back to my local server. How  is it done? my guess is to intercept all dns request and point them to my custom server....

This is a snippet of what i have so far for the dns request.

```
import socket
import sys

host = ''
port = socket.getservbyname('domain') #get dns port dynamically

udp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # udp socket
udp_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)

print 'udp socket created...'

try:
    udp_socket.bind((host,port))
    print 'bind successful'
except socket.error as msg:
    print msg
    sys.exit()

while True:
    data,addr = udp_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    if data:
        print data,addr
    else: break

udp_socket.close()
```

Shows all dns request on the server from clients... now how to redirect to the my localhost

Forgot to mention I am using windows...

Answer (score 0):

Your approach may work, but depending on your actual requirements it may not be very efficient. A more natural approach would be to use iptables on your host to catch unidentified HTTP traffic and send that back to your local web server.

See this site for a recipe setting this up using PHP. To modify it using python should not be too hard. http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Using_iptables_and_PHP_to_create_a_captive_portal

Comment: Yes i saw this post. But iptables won't work on windows. I am looking for a windows alternative.